# Knockout.JS with bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm attempting to use [Bootstrap Selectpicker](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) along with knockout.js. There is already a custom binding out there that works for the multiselect version of the selectpicker ([seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/9EQeg/199/)), but I need it to work with the single select version. I thought it was going to be as simple as changing the `ko.observableArray` to a `ko.observable` and removing the `multiple` attribute -- but this doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas on how to get this working?

[Fiddle with the binding and my updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/9EQeg/200/)

Comment: I don't understand what is not working in your demo. Could you please be more explicit? From what I can see the selected value reflects what your drop down selection is...

Comment: The problem comes with the initial value (in the demo, `teamID`). It's set to 2 in `teamID`, but the select shows it as being 1 initially.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**  See below for alternate solution

the problem is with your selectPicker.init function.

You need to call the options binding, not the value binding.  the options.init sets the initial internal state, when this bypassed the options.update function will reset the value.

```
// regular select and observable so call the default value binding
ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
```

change to

```
// regular select and observable so call the default value binding
ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
```

---

**EDIT**

Ok, I took you sample back to basics to use the standard options bindings to get the normal select working.

Then use the selectpicker binding solely to initialise and refresh.  It will synchronize to the select on its own.

Prior to Knockout 3, the selectPicker update function would have been invoked if any of the bindings on the element caused an update ( like updating options, value or selectedOptions ).  With Knockout 3 the bindings now fire independently ( good thing ), but you now need to use subscriptions to get notified when either the options or value/selectedOptions changes.

I think you will see this is now a lot simpler and there is no distinct between single and multiple select in your custom binding.  This now works if either the teamItems or itemID observable is updated.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Multiple Select -->
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: teamIDs, 
                   options: teamItems, 
                   optionsText: 'text', 
                   optionsValue : 'id', 
                   selectPicker: {}" multiple="true"></select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
  after: ['options'],   /* KO 3.0 feature to ensure binding execution order */
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
     var $element = $(element);
     $element.addClass('selectpicker').selectpicker();

     var doRefresh = function() {
         $element.selectpicker('refresh');
     },  subscriptions = [];

     // KO 3 requires subscriptions instead of relying on this binding's update
     // function firing when any other binding on the element is updated.

     // Add them to a subscription array so we can remove them when KO
     // tears down the element.  Otherwise you will have a resource leak.
     var addSubscription = function(bindingKey) {
         var targetObs = allBindingsAccessor.get(bindingKey);

         if ( targetObs && ko.isObservable(targetObs )) {
            subscriptions.push( targetObs.subscribe(doRefresh) );
         }
     };

     addSubscription('options');
     addSubscription('value');           // Single
     addSubscription('selectedOptions'); // Multiple

     ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() { 
         while( subscriptions.length ) {
             subscriptions.pop().dispose();
         }
     } );
   },
   update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
   }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does seem to have worked for the initial setting, but now the `teamID` value is not updated when the select option is changed. Any ideas on why that would be? http://jsfiddle.net/9EQeg/34/

Comment: +1 Thanks, this works a treat! One small quirk in the html data-bind attribute is the position of 'selectPicker' has to be after 'options' otherwise the last item in the collection isn't initially displayed, but is after another item has been selected.

Comment: Under KO 3 you can add an 'after' property to the binding handler and KO will make sure those handlers are invoked before yours, regardless of the order in the data-bind attribute.  But you are correct for KO 2.x

Comment: Actually, KO 3 tracks which bindings you use in the update function (see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html ). Your approach fails for computed expressions (see http://jsfiddle.net/c2gbak5m/ )

Answer (score 5):

Knockout has excellent and robust support for computed bindings (for example `item().children.length > foo().maxChildren`) and the current answers fail to support these.

So as further improvement to RobertSlanley's answer, and based on [Knockout's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), I have created the following binding.

Knockout will handle the observable subscriptions by itself, so long as we access them in the update method.
Which means we can remove the subscription cruft and just concentrate on what we really want to do:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
    after: ['options', 'value', 'selectedOptions'],
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).addClass('selectpicker').selectpicker();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        /* KO 3.3 will track any bindings we depend on
           and call us when any of them changes */
        allBindingsAccessor.get('options');
        allBindingsAccessor.get('value');
        allBindingsAccessor.get('selectedOptions');

        $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
    }
};
```

[Here's a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2gbak5m/2/)

Comment: But you are binding your value and options against NON observable entities.

dc.item().A = "A" will not update the picker.  If field "A" was an observable then my approach still works.

Comment: Robert, your approach fails to embrace KO's approach to observable expressions. KO's most powerful feature is computed bindings like `data-bind="text: item().isVisible ? 'foo' : 'bar'"`. With your approach you subscribe to the result of the binding at init time, whereas the builtin bindings in KO track changes to the whole expression. I'm not saying your  solution is wrong, it's just not idiomatic

Comment: this is the answer that worked for me, not sure i understand the difference between accepted answer and this one fully, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't yet comment on above answer, but there is a little mistake in the HTML-part:

The selected values binding should be `selectedOptions` and not `selectOptions`.

#### HTML

```
<!-- Multiple Select -->
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: teamIDs, 
               options: teamItems, 
               optionsText: 'text', 
               optionsValue : 'id', 
               selectPicker: {}" multiple="true"></select>
```